# Unable to find Matching Set of Capabilities and ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, chrome-web-driver

Here is the situation.  I downloaded the chrome webdriver, unzipped the file, and went through the steps for setting the path through system properties. I am still unable to open chrome from Eclipse. Please help.

[Unable to find matching set of capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x266I.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are giving wrong parameter in system properties

1. **Gecko driver** is for **firefox**
2. If you have already downloaded chrome driver simply replace geckodriver.exe with chromedriver.exe.Otherwise, Download chrome driver and place it in your folder given in system properties and run your code.
3. Your code will appear as:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\...\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   // **Note**: complete your path above
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.  Now, one more question.  I tried setting the system variable for chromedriver so that I wouldn't have to write out that whole thing (System.setProperty etc.).  When I did that and commented the phrase out, I got the executable path error.  It works fine with FF but not so much with Chrome.  What should I do?

Comment: Add path of folder containing chromedriver.exe i.e  "D:path\to\"  in environment variable(environment variables >  system variables > path).
restart your eclipse. It will pick chromedriver

https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I got it to work by making it a user variable instead of a system's variable.  Not sure why it worked out this way but it did. If you guys have any ideas as to why it worked out this way versus making it a system's variable, feel free to share.